# How to set gdsl groovy script base object

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, dsl, groovyshell

Have main java class evaluating groovy scipt

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setProperty("text", "some text");

CompilerConfiguration configuration = new CompilerConfiguration();
configuration.setScriptBaseClass(MyBaseClass.class.getName());

GroovyShell groovyShell = new GroovyShell(binding, configuration);
result = groovyShell.evaluate(file);
```

To have autocomplete groovy scripts in idea (and other IDEs), I use gdsl file

```
def ctx = context(scope: scriptScope())

contributor(ctx) {
    property name: "text", type: "java.lang.String"
    method name: 'annotate', type: 'void', params: [closure: 'groovy.lang.Closure']
}
```

But I'd like to put in gdsl MyBaseClass to get IDE tips and autocomplete with all my class methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
def ctx = context(scope: scriptScope())

contributor(ctx, {
    delegatesTo(findClass('com.example.MyBaseClass'))
})
```